# Multiply 1D arrays a[k] and d[j] into a matrix m[j,k]

Tags: python, numpy

```
>>> import numpy as np
```

Suppose I have the following two arrays

```
>>> a = np.array([a1,a2,a3,a4,a5])
>>> d = np.array([d1,d2,d3])
```

I'd like to know how to operate the two arrays in order to obtain a 5x3 matrix:

```
>>> m
   np.array([[a1*d1, a2*d1, a3*d1, a4*d1, a5*d1],
             [a1*d2, a2*d2, a3*d2, a4*d2, a5*d2],
             [a1*d3, a2*d3, a3*d3, a4*d3, a5*d3])
>>> m.shape
   (3, 5)
```

I wasn't able to find an appropriate numpy function to achieve this. Even if the final matrix comes out transposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use broadcasting:

```
a[None, :] * d[:, None]


In [2]: a = np.arange(5)

In [3]: d = np.arange(3)

In [4]: a[None, :] * d[:, None]
Out[4]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]])
```

You can use np.newaxis instead of None, it does the same (np.newaxis is just an alias, with a more explicit name). What it does it to add an additional axis to `a` or `d`:

```
In [5]: a[None, :].shape
Out[5]: (1, 5)
```

Broadcasting is a very efficient tool to perform operations on arrays in numpy, read more about it [in the doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

As a remark, `a * d[:, None]` would also work, but I find the first formulation to be more explicit.

Comment: Try `np.outer(d, a)` instead.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ ok, but outer is restricted to division or multiplication between a and d. With broadcasting you could do the same for addition, for example.

Comment: There's also `np.add.outer(d, a)` and basically an `outer` for the basic arithmetic ufuncs.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to answer. Indeed `a.shape` is `(5,)` which is not `(1,5)` as needed. I'll read more about it on the link you gave.

Answer (score 0):

I like the @P.Camilleri [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50143168/1887559). This one just for the sake of diversity...

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x,y = np.random.random(5), np.random.random(3)      
>>> x
array([0.5538738 , 0.31099761, 0.42709952, 0.28999541, 0.76811293])
>>> y
array([0.80281963, 0.31063054, 0.20141215])

>>> np.array([x])*np.array([y]).T
array([[0.44466076, 0.24967499, 0.34288388, 0.23281401, 0.61665614],
       [0.17205012, 0.09660536, 0.13267015, 0.09008143, 0.23859933],
       [0.11155691, 0.0626387 , 0.08602303, 0.0584086 , 0.15470727]])
```

Comment: Avoid from `numpy import *.` It replaces built-in functions like `sum` and can cause headaches.

Comment: A flaw of this approach is that it creates new arrays for x and y, whereas x[:, None] is just a view on x, without memory overhead; for large arrays it might matter.

Comment: @P.Camilleri agree with first - bad habit... Sorry. Agree with the second too (as I stated, I like your approach). But your broadcast is a bit less readable for naive eyes, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

A few timings:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> 
>>> kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=10000)
>>> 
>>> a = np.random.random(100)
>>> d = np.random.random(60)
>>>
>>> timeit("d[:, None] * a", **kwds)
0.10106271505355835
>>> timeit("d[:, None] @ a[None]", **kwds)
0.08171644899994135
>>> timeit("np.dot(d[:, None], a[None])", **kwds)
0.08377223135903478
>>> timeit("d.reshape(-1, 1) * a", **kwds)
0.11084615904837847
>>> timeit("np.einsum('i,j->ij', d, a)", **kwds)
0.0618918058462441
>>> timeit("np.tensordot(d, a, ((),()))", **kwds)
0.23450013296678662
>>> timeit("np.c_[d] * a", **kwds)
0.19284361507743597
>>> timeit("np.multiply(*np.ix_(d, a))", **kwds)
0.16771024512127042
>>> timeit("np.multiply.outer(d, a)", **kwds)
0.09988314099609852
>>> timeit("np.outer(d, a)", **kwds)
0.11399263981729746
```

`einsum` looks fastest.